# Tree Density Calculator

Tags: qgis, density

In Tree density Calculator in QGIS what format is the 'Image' requested. I have a GeoTIFF image that I would like to calculate the tree density.

Comment: Have you checked with the plugin provider?

Comment: Have you gone through the [documentation](https://treedensitycalculator.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) and tutorial dataset?